# HTML - Meaning of "for" attribute of label tag

Tags: html, css, label

```html
<label for="days">Day:</label>
<select id="days">
<option>Monday</option>
<option>Tuesday</option>
<option>Wednesday</option>
</select>
```

In the above example, even if I delete the code `for="days"`, I get the same visual result. What is the `for` attribute of the `label` tag used for? Should I include it or not?

Comment: When used together in a form with the `<label>` element, the `for` attribute specifies which form element a label is bound to.

When used together with the `<output>` element, the `for` attribute specifies the relationship between the result of the calculation, and the elements used in the calculation.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label